# Incompatible types in assignment of int to char

Tags: c

```
void trinti1()
{
    int b,lines;
    char ch[20];

    FILE* file = fopen ("Kordinates.txt", "r");

    while(!feof(file))
    {
        ch = fgetc(file);
        if(ch == '\n')
        {
            lines++;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Hello guys I am trying to count lines in file, but seems `fgetc(file)` returns `int` and it can't be converted to char. Help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `feof()` to control the termination of your loop; it doesn't become true until *after* you've failed to read a character. Each input function returns a result that tells you whether it was able to read anything; use that to decide when the loop is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `ch` is not a `char`, it is `char[20]` - an array of 20 characters. You cannot assign a result of `fgetc` to it, because `fgetc` returns an `int` (which contains either a single `char`, or an `EOF` mark).

Change the declaration of `ch` to `int ch` to fix this problem. You can also drop the call to `feof` because it happens at the wrong time anyway (you call it after read operations, not before read operations).

```
for (;;) {
    int ch = fgetc(file);
    if (ch == EOF) break;
    if (ch == '\n') lines++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void trinti1()
{
    int b,lines=0;
    int ch;

    FILE* file = fopen ("Kordinates.txt", "r");

    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(file)))
    {
        if(ch == '\n')
        {
            ++lines;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```